# How do I get this HTML form to submit in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm a bit of a newbie on Ruby on Rails, but I decided to give my hand at a Table Reservation Application I've always wanted to make. I was stumbling around on how to create a typical quantity increment form and I came across some info, ultimately my form ended up looking like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZVNoz

It's not that fancy but it works (doesn't work on the codepen but it works on my project), here's the catch, now I need this form to submit and pass through my Reservations Controller, which looks like this:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def create
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    reservation.save
  end

  private

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:user_email, :num_of_people, :reservation_time, :table_id)
  end
end
```

So essentially, when the User clicks on the table that they want to reserve, this little form comes up, they select how many guests are with them, and hit submit and boom, it records who made the reservation (by the user's email), and the number of people with them (as indicated using the quantity indicator with the plus and minus signs), the time of the reservation, and the table id. My problems is, I'm not sure how to get the submit and the reservations controller to communicate to each other. Any ideas? Am I missing any crucial steps?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Where is the form located at? And where should the user go after submission? To the index of the reservations controller?

Comment: @Alexander Trust

The form is located on the Reservations Controller Index. In fact, everything will be done on there. The user clicks on "Reservations" link, and on the reservations link a floor map will show up, they select whatever table they want and then said form will pop up asking "How many guests?" After that, they select the quantity and hit submit, and then the form will disappear and then the table will turn yellow to show that the user has now "queued" up the table they want and it is now under their name. So the form should redirect back to the same page it was originally on.

Comment: @Alexander Trust, I hope I answered that correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm a bit of a newbie on Ruby on Rails

Welcome!!

---

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :reservations

#app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @reservation = Reservation.new
   end

   def create
      @reservation = Reservation.new reservation_params
      @reservation.save
   end

   private

   def reservation_params
      params.require(:reservation).permit(:user_email, :num_of_people, :reservation_time, :table_id)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following form:

```
#app/views/reservations/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @reservation do |f| %>
   <%= f.email_field :user_email %>
   <%= f.number_field :num_of_people %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to create a reservation by accessing `url.com/reservations/new`

---

To explain how it works, Rails is built on top of the [*Object Orientated*](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/object-oriented-programming) principle -- *everything* in your application should be, or at least serves, an object.

Your [routes are object orientated](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web), your controllers should be object orientated, and your flow should be object orientated:

[image]

Thus, when you ask about how your `new` form will communicate with your controller, the answer is that you have to tie it in with the various routes you've defined for the controller.

Specifically, if you have a `new` action, you should also have a `create` action - which your form will be able to send its data to.

Your forms are just HTML -- they will post their data to the URL you define in the `form_for` block to your controller. The result will be that you're able to invoke the appropriate data in the `customers#create` method, which will save the data to the db.

Answer (score 1):

@kambo_trick3y: Yes you did answer correctly. It's just necessary to know, what or if to change or add accordingly.

In your case you have to change the index method. From the form, you are sending a new parameter, you can name it what you like, I think yours is `quantitiy`. For example in a normal search field, people often use `q` as the parameter, but you could name it like you want via the name field. Then you do something like this:

```
def index
  if params[:quantitiy].present?
   # define variables here

  else
   # define other variables here for the normal index view

  end
end
```

I see you did the form on your own, hence you would have to add the path by hand... I guess it would be just `/reservations` then. You can find out the right paths by doing `rake routes`. If you're working with a form helper in Rails, your form tag would look like:

```
<%= form_tag reservations_path, method: :get do %>
   # put the content of your form here
<% end %>
```

I cannot say for sure, but it should work like this. I am using a similar form for my search, and the form is present at different views, in different controllers, so the only thing I have to change is the path for the get method and the controller method too.